# SQL query column does not exist error

Tags: postgresql, quoted-identifier

I'm totally new in this area please tell me how to fix my problem.

when I write this query "`SELECT * FROM places`" in my database everything is okay.
However when I change it to "`SELECT * FROM places WHERE eventId=2`", I get error. Please look at this image.

[image]

as you can see, `eventId` column is exist. Why my query throws error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've almost certainly added the column names in a case-sensitive environment. (PgAdmin comes to mind.) Lowercase them in that same environment to avoid the need to quote fields.

Or change your query to:

```
select * from places where "eventId" = 2
```